# Laravel - Dynamic APP_NAME config variable based on domain

Tags: php, laravel

How do I overwrite the APP_NAME config variable *dynamically* based on the domain/hostname so that I can reference it in all Controllers and Blade templates?

OR how can I create a global variable (single record from a Model) that changes dynamically based on the domain, so that it is accessible in all Controllers and Blade templates?

I have 3 domains - each for a different athletic conference/League - that share 100% the same code. Currently, I have a function in **/app/Helper/Helper.php** that I call from every Controller. This gets the correct League based on the domain, and allows me to send the correct set of data to each view.

```
// Get league info based on domain
public static function getLeague(Request $request)
{
  $host = $request->getHost();

  if (App::environment('production')) {
    // Some fancy Substring logic to get the domain name
  } else {
    // Manually set $host to one of my domains for offline debugging
  }

  $league = League::where(['url' => $host])->first();

  return $league;
}
```

The above works great for Views and Controllers I have built.

However, I also leverage several out-of-the-box views and *email templates* for User Registration, Login, Forgot Password, etc., that use APP_NAME.

Some of them (like the Login or Register screens) have a typical Controller so I can call my Helper function and just pass the League to the view. But for others, like *email templates*, I've tried going down the rabbit trail of Controllers and Functions that eventually produce the email content, and I cannot find where to call my Helper function and pass the League Name to the view.

An example of an email template using APP_NAME, that I cannot figure out how to pass $league to it instead of it using the config variable, is:
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/html/message.blade.php

So I'm stuck trying to figure out how to set the APP_NAME (or automatically calling my Helper function and creating a global $league variable that I can use in Controllers and Blade templates).

I have tried updating 'name' in **/config/app.php**, but it errors when trying to call the Helper function.

```
<?php

use App\Helper\Helper;
//dd($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$league = $league = Helper::getLeagueWithHost($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

return [
    'name' => $league->name,
....
]
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in C:\...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 258
```

This all wouldn't be a problem to set manually in each .env file, but I have an AWS CodePipeline that deploys to each domain upon GitHub push, so I'd have to update 3 .env files every time.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish the ultimate goal, but not in the manner being requested in my initial question.

As part of the AWS CodePipeline deployment, there are "Appspec" events that fire at various times in the process (application-stop, before-install, after-install, application-start, and validate-service).

I wrote a Bash script in the "after-install" event that checks the IP of the hostname (returns the Private IP of the current Lightsail instance being deployed). And depending on the hostname IP, it changes line 2 of my .env file to the desired APP_NAME.

There is some hard-coding involved, mapping each Lightsail Private IP to an APP_NAME (meh), but as long as I do not delete and recreate a Lightsail instance, the Private IPs will remain static. The only way to avoid that would be to solve the initial question of updating the APP_NAME at runtime based on the URL/domain.

So, if someone else is trying to solve this problem at runtime when a page loads, this solution will not work for you.